# Run Genymotion from Remote Location

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am facing a problem while running my own System from remote location. Genymotion is working absolutely fine on my machine, But when I tried to access my machine from the remote location it just stop working with attached messages.

[image]

Comment: i cannot see any `attached image`

Comment: Yes, Just updated. There was some issue.

Comment: try [this](http://madcoda.com/2014/05/solving-genymotion-unable-to-connect-to-your-virtual-device-error/) if it works

Comment: Thanks hrskrs, But it didn't worked.

Comment: thats all i had. Hope youll find solution :/

Comment: No, Still I am looking for some solution.

Comment: Can you please explain the remote connection you are using?

Comment: did you solve this?